# GroupBy using LINQ but base distinct on another column, and still be able to count other records

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

How should I run a GroupBy based on Id using LINQ when there is an object similar to following:

```
public class foo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }  
    public string lang { get; set; }  
    public int displayOrder { get; set; } 
    public int count { get; set; } 

}
```

The list could be:

```
 id = 1, name="test1", lang = "en", displayOrder = 1, count = 1
 id = 1, name="test2", lang = "fr", displayOrder = 2, count = 2
 id = 1, name="test3", lang = "de", displayOrder = 3, count = 1
 id = 2, name="test4", lang = "en", displayOrder = 2, count = 1
 id = 2, name="test5", lang = "fr", displayOrder = 3, count = 1
 id = 3, name="test6", lang = "en", displayOrder = 6, count = 1
 id = 3, name="test7", lang = "fr", displayOrder = 4, count = 1
 id = 4, name="test8", lang = "en", displayOrder = 5, count = 1
 id = 5, name="test9", lang = "de", displayOrder = 6, count = 1
```

I want to run LINQ so that it Groups By Id values, but the distinct id values should be filtered based on lang e.g. "fr", if nothing is available in "fr" it should output only default language record for "en"
 but should also Count the total number of records based on Id, it should retrieve following results for above:

```
 id = 1, name="test2", lang = "fr", displayOrder = 2, count = 4
 id = 2, name="test5", lang = "fr", displayOrder = 3, count = 2
 id = 3, name="test7", lang = "fr", displayOrder = 4, count = 2
 id = 4, name="test8", lang = "en", displayOrder = 5, count = 1
 id = 5, name="test9", lang = "de", displayOrder = 6, count = 1
```

Please, is there a way to do something like this using LINQ ?
All of you LINQ experts, I'm ideally looking for query using lambda, this would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the target language to the front, and select the first item in a group:

```
var query = from f in foos
            group f by f.id into g
            let lang = (from f in g
                        orderby 
                          f.lang == "fr" ? 0 : 1,
                          f.lang == "en" ? 0 : 1,
                          f.lang
                         select f).First()
            select new 
            {
              id = g.Key,
              lang.name,
              lang.lang,
              lang.displayOrder,
              count = g.Sum(f => f.count)
            };
```

This assumes that pairs (id, lang) are unique.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/v0TGqX)

Comment: Since this is essentially the same answer that I typed up, I deleted my post, and slightly edited yours.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - thank you! I usually use `FirstOrDefault` because for some reason the `linq-to-entities` world complains about `First`

Comment: Demo is very useful but I've realized that the count also is part of the object. I've edited the description, so foo also has count. Please could you help me with getting the counts based on foo. - @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @maverick Since you make a new `count`, you need a new `foo` anyway. Add a second `Select` after the anonymous type to convert `f.Foo` into a new `foo` object, like this: http://ideone.com/6xDhR4.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - the issue is if count is other than 1 , e.g. id = 1 then the count should be sum, please note :
id = 1, name="test2", lang = "fr", displayOrder = 2, count = 4

If I select a new foo then it still gives 3 as count.

Comment: @maverick - You just need to change the `Count` to `Sum`. I have updated the answer

Comment: @Aducci where does f.count come from? did you miss a Select call?

Comment: @EthanLi - `count` is a property on `foo`. The OP updated the class definition

Comment: Right, I need to change me answer then, thanks @Aducci

Answer (score 0):

This may run slightly faster as it does not need to go through all items in the group for ordering.

```
var res = data
    .GroupBy(d => d.id)
    .Select(g => new {
        id = g.Key,
        count = g.Sum(d => d.count),
        Lang = g.FirstOrDefault(d => d.lang == "fr") ?? g.First()
    })
    .Select(g => new {
        g.id,
        g.Lang.lang,
        g.Lang.name,
        g.Lang.displayOrder,
        g.count
    })
    .ToList();
```